# Angular scope function executed multiple times

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have defined a function on scope. And when I call it from the view inside {{}} it executes X number of times.

Controller

```
function testCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.myFunc = function(name) {
       return "Hello " + name;
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<div>{{myFunc('Joe')}}</div>
```

You can see it in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/rbRvD/2/

Or with Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LLQ7cKs2fEoBwv0C5XPE

I guess this is done the wrong way, but why is it executed so many times?

Comment: Updated with plunker link

Comment: Can you tell how you skip over this problem exactly ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your function is run 10 times. Why 10? Why not 100?

The answer [is in the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch):

> The watch listener may change the model, which may trigger other
>   listeners to fire. This is achieved by rerunning the watchers until no
>   changes are detected. The **rerun iteration limit is 10** to prevent an
>   infinite loop deadlock.

When you see this happening, it means you are changing the model in such a way that Angular has to rerun the digest and fire the watches again. In your particular case you are calling a function that updates a counter, which is displayed on the page. When the counter value changes it runs the digest again, which calls the function that updates the counter, etc, etc.

Angular expects you (and indeed encourages you) to change the model and let the view respond to those changes, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Missed this part in my response...
Ok, then it's not an issue, I guess? The counter was just an example to make it clearer. With a log I suppose it would have logged one time for each watcher?

Comment: Any way to reduse it? Because in applcation we are always using set of properties to manupulate values. For example Full Name = FirstName + LastName, Address = City +  Pin. All property are part of user model. Now if city changed no need to manupulate Full Name again. It can lead to poor performance.

Comment: @Nitul it's been a while since I've used Angular. I'd suggest asking this in another question.

Answer (score 12):

This is expected behaviour. Angular expressions (`{{expression}}`) are re-evaluated on each [$digest loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693933/1095616) (sometimes multiple times per loop). This means that expressions should stay light in computational terms.

For that matter, expression evaluation should not result in an AJAX call or some other intensive or asynchronous operation, or if it has to, than you should be caching the results.

Comment: zetetic's answer is technically correct but it answers the plunkr, not the question posted here(they are different). This answer is for the question posted here.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJs does not suggest you to change scope's model on rendering.  If you want to change your scope's model, do it in Controller or Directive.

Think of view as a place to display data (scope values in this case) only, all the modifying of the data should be in Controller or Directive.

Comment: If you mean the counter value its only there to make my example clearer. You could put a log there instead.