# Call an AngularJS function inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was trying to see if there is a way to call a function I designed inside the scope:

```
<ul class="ui-listview ui-radiobutton" ng-repeat="meter in meters">
    <li class = "ui-divider">
        {{meter.DESCRIPTION}}
        {{htmlgeneration}}
    </li>
</ul>

$scope.htmlgeneration = function()
{
    ...
}
```

The function is called `htmlgeneration`.  Essentially, what I want to do is dynamically append HTML inside the `li` element while using AngularJS.

Comment: While calling a function from HTmL like @SomeKittens said , Your function will be called more than once . Why ? Answer is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164230/angular-scope-function-executed-multiple-times) . So be careful when calling function from HTML . It may slowdown the loading of your page .

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yep, just add parenthesis (calling the function).  Make sure the function is in scope and actually returns something.

```
<ul class="ui-listview ui-radiobutton" ng-repeat="meter in meters">
  <li class = "ui-divider">
    {{ meter.DESCRIPTION }}
    {{ htmlgeneration() }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is there a way to do it using parameters?

Comment: @Serge Yes, pass the parameters to the function as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my problem was related to conflicts with Django tags. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302928/angularjs-with-django-conflicting-template-tags) was helpful.

What worked for me was a simple solution involving using `ng-bind` and changing the code to something like this:

```
<ul class="ui-listview ui-radiobutton" ng-repeat="meter in meters">
  <li class="ui-divider" ng-bind="htmlgeneration(meter.DESCRIPTION)">
  </li>
</ul>
```