# AngularJS Function gets called many times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a very simple js file for my angular app.

```
angular.module('Account', ['firebase'])

  .value('fbURL', 'https://myURL.firebaseio.com/')

  .service('fbRef', function(fbURL) {
     return new Firebase(fbURL)
  })

  .controller('Authorization', function($scope, $firebase, $firebaseObject, fbRef){

      var auth = this;

      auth.loginEnabled = function() {

        alert('false');

        return false;
      } 

      auth.loginEmail = function() {


      }

  });
```

The `auth.loginEnabled` function gets called many times (the alert appears many times) when my html loads. Why is this?

In my html

- ng-app is declared in my html tag as ng-app="Account"
- ng-controller is delcared in my `<div class="container">` that wraps an if for angular
- ng-if is declared twice, once for a true return and once for a false.

In short, here is my html code: (all your missing is the ng-app code described above)

```
<div class="container login-container" ng-controller="Authorization as auth">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <form class="" action="" method="">
                        <div class="card-container manual-flip">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <div class="cover">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $base; ?>assets/img/rotating_card_thumb2.png"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="content" ng-if="auth.loginEnabled()">
                                        <div class="main">
                                            <h3 class="name">Login</h3>
                                            <p class="profession">My Account</p>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="email" ng-model="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail Address">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="password" ng-model="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="footer">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Login <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="content" ng-if="!auth.loginEnabled()">
                                        <div class="main">
                                            <h3 class="name">Login</h3>
                                            <p class="profession">Temporarily Unavailable</p>
                                            <p class="text-center">We are currently updating our system for a better user experience! Please check back within a few hours.</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="footer">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $base; ?>" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Return Home</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="back">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm wanting to disable the login function all together at certain times, not see if the user is already logged in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular scope function executed multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164230/angular-scope-function-executed-multiple-times)

Comment: It's advised to avoid function where it's not needed, Use a "LoginAuthenticated" boolean variable that will manifest the user status, this won't cause angular to rerun the watch listener.

Comment: Okay.... that doesn't help me though. How would I fix it?

Comment: I'm wanting to see if the user can login. It will be disabled at certain times. (the login function that is)

Comment: As i said, just assign a flag value that will indicate whatever the user is logged in or not. the `ng-if` will get a notify when the variable will be changed.

Comment: That's not what I want. I don't to see if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: I WANT TO SEE IF THE LOGIN PAGE SHOULD BE ENABLED OR NOT.

Comment: Firstly, I came to help you, so you can lose the "CAPITAL LETTERS" i can see very clearly without them. Secondly, you can enable or disable the login page section without using a function, you can do that by setting a variable that will came back from the server whenever the user is authenticated or not, this variable will be notify whoever watching him, that means `ng-if` that it should re-render and thus the html of the login page will be destroyed or created by the value of the variable.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do that without calling a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Orel mentioned, the cause for the repeated alert is simply that your `loginEnabled` function is called upon every digest cycle. Without going into too much detail, Angular is frequently reevaluating those functions and values bound to the scope to ensure your UI is representing your data accurately.

Thus, it would be preferable to assign the `loginEnabled` value to a Boolean and query that within the scope:

```
auth.loginEnabled = false;

$rootScope.$on('myAuthenticationEvent', function () {
  auth.loginEnabled = true;
});
```

The usage of the $rootScope isn't necessary, but serves to demonstrate that some other function in your controller (perhaps a Firebase observer) could be responsible for updating your `auth.loginEnabled` value. Hope this helps!

Comment: I just get more errors with this. Being $rootScope is undefined. I thought Angular was supposed to be easy!

Comment: When the page loads, I just want to check in my firebase db and see if an admin has disabled or enabled the login feature of the site. If the login feature is disabled then the login form will be hidden. If it's enabled it will show the login form. That's all  I want to do.

Comment: Remember to inject $rootScope if you want to use that part of my example.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your controller is called twice, may be because of this

`ng-controller="Authorization as auth` is mentioned in your view and also while configuring your route you might also include controller there too. like below

```
                 url: '/your url',
                 config: {
                     templateUrl: 'url',
                     controllerUrl: 'url',
                     controller:'Authorization'
                 }
```

If that is the case then, change your code to

```
                 url: '/your url',
                 config: {
                     templateUrl: 'url',
                     controllerUrl: 'url',
                 }
```