# AngularJS - How to throttle unnecessary calls to functions

Tags: angularjs

I have any application that has a wizard implemented that allows users to put in dimension of various parts. There are a lot of dimensions involved in each part. And there are multiple parts.

I have implemented a function that tells user what is the current unit of measurement (mm/cm/mil/inch). This function is used quite a lot in the wizard. The problem is the number of calls to this function seem unreasonably high. Also, calls to other functions that have nothing to do with the aforementioned function also endup calling the function for whatever reason.

Is there a way throttle these calls?
Why do calls to unrelated functions (I have many in my application) endup calling this function?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5qmmy27/)

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="con">
    <h1 ng-click="callOtherFunc()">
    Click
    </h1>
    {{callFunction()}}
    {{callFunction()}}
    {{callFunction()}}
    {{callFunction()}}
    {{callFunction()}}
    <br/>
    {{counter}}
    <br/>    
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("con",function($scope){
    $scope.counter = 0;  

  $scope.callFunction = function(){     
    $scope.counter = $scope.counter + 1; 
    return "mm";
  }

  $scope.callOtherFunc = function(){    
  }  
})
```

Comment: Perhaps this holds the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164230/angular-scope-function-executed-multiple-times

Comment: So the short answer is these calls cannot be throttled.