# angularjs push to array adding ten elements

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, and this has been driving me nuts for several days.  HELP!!!  I've condensed the problem into as simple a code snippet as I could..  I've set up an array called indexArray in the Controller, and I want to push values to it from HTML via the function pushIndex().  The problem is that the push function adds ten identical elements to the array.  When I list the array with the {{indexArray}} statement after the push, it looks like this:

[4,5,6,7,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]

Where I only wanted one "9" pushed, it added ten of them.

The same thing happens with strings, quotes, etc.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
var app = angular.module('myDataApp',[]);
app.controller('myDataController',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.indexArray=[4,5,6,7];
    $scope.pushIndex=function(num){
        $scope.indexArray.push(num);
   };
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myDataApp" ng-controller="myDataController">
{{ pushIndex(9) }}
{{ indexArray }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry in advance if the solution is painfully simple or this question has been asked before.  Thanks!  -UDM

Comment: This kind of angular expressions are ment to be side-effect free and angular will call your `{{ pushIndex(9) }}` expression many, many times (it won't even stop at 10). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164230/angular-scope-function-executed-multiple-times) for example.

Answer (score 3):

Calling a function like this `{{ pushIndex(9) }}` will run the digest loop infinitely.

This will work for you instead

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
var app = angular.module('myDataApp',[]);
app.controller('myDataController',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.indexArray=[4,5,6,7];
    $scope.pushIndex=function(num){
        $scope.indexArray.push(num);
   };
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myDataApp" ng-controller="myDataController">
<span ng-init="result=pushIndex(9)">{{result}}</span>
{{ indexArray }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works like a charm, and ended five days of *SHEER FRUSTRATION* :-)

Comment: If you can please up vote and select this as the answer to this question, it would be much appreciated.